# Orthogonal Projections Help

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

This problem is through webwork. Webwork keeps telling me I have the wrong answer, and I'm not sure why. I've done similar problems and have gotten the correct answer. Here it is:

> $$v=(-18,-14,-19) \\
> u_1=(-2,2,-2) \\
> u_2=(-4,7,2)$$
>
> Find the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the subspace $V \subset \Bbb R^3$ spanned by $u_1$ and $u_2$.

$$\operatorname{proj}_V(v)=\frac {v \cdot u_1}{u_1 \cdot u_1}u_1 + \frac{v\cdot u_2}{u_2 \cdot u_2}u_2$$

$$v\cdot u_1=46 \\
u_1 \cdot u_1=12 \\
v\cdot u_2=-64 \\
u_2\cdot u_2=69$$

$$ \begin{align}\implies \operatorname{proj}_V(v)&=\frac {46}{12}u_1-\frac{64}{69}u_2 \\
&=(-\frac {92}{12},\frac {92}{12},-\frac {92}{12}) + (\frac {256}{69}, -\frac {448}{69}, -\frac {128}{69}) \\
&=(-\frac {91}{23}, \frac {27}{23}, -\frac {219}{23})\end{align}$$
 is my final answer

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: edit* meant to type  -64/69

Comment: If you want to edit something, there's a button on your post to do so

Comment: @P.Lin I've formatted your question.  Make sure it is still correct.  In the future, you can find help adding MathJax to your questions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The formula you are using is fine if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal.  Since they are not, though, you first can use Gram-Schmidt to get an orthogonal basis for V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct formula to use is $$\left((u_1\cdot u_1)(u_2.u_2) - (u_1\cdot u_2)^2\right)proj(v) = \left({(u_2\cdot u_2)(u_1\cdot v) - (u_1\cdot u_2)(u_2.v)}\right)u_1+\left({(u_1\cdot u_1)(u_2\cdot v) - (u_1\cdot u_2)(u_1.v)}\right)u_2$$

assuming your numbers are correct, $$\begin{align}(12 \times 69-18^2)prom(v) &= (69\times 46 - 18\times(-64))u_1 + (12 \times(-64)-18\times46)u_2 \\
504 proj(v)&=4326u_1-1596u_2
\\&=4326(-2,2-2)-1596(-4,7,2)=(-2268,-2520,-11844)\\
proj(v) &=(-4.5,-5,-23.5)\end{align}$$